# reconcile yearly credit card statements

Tags: accounting, software, financial-statements

**Background:**

My clients get credit card statements every year. He wants me to find out that whether the Bank is going fair calculation or not.

**Question**: Is there any quick and accurate way to do the job? Currently, I am worried because - first, if I do it manually it will a lot of time and secondly, there are chances of human errors.

Information from the comments:

- I have 5y x 12m = 60 statements in front of me.

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the software recommendation from the question.

Comment: They _only_ get them once a year? Seems like they/you should be able to do this monthly, or set up an excel template with a few inputs (I'm assuming that they're wanting to verify interest calculations)?

Comment: Monthly, for sure is a good approach going forward. But for now, I have 5y x 12m = 60 statements in front of me. Secondly, if I do good with this task. I will have to do maintain/keep-a-watch on other people's statements too. So even if I do it monthly, for 20 people again it is time consuming.

Comment: You describe them as "clients" so I assume they are paying you to provide this service.  Have you had a cost/ benefit discussion with these clients?   Presumably, the probability that the credit card company computes interest incorrectly is low.  Presumably, you can get a pretty quick approximation of what the interest should be just from the average balance over the month.  If the approximation is roughly right, it would seem silly to expend $10 worth of time to verify that $0.10 of interest was calculated correctly.

Comment: @JustinCave totally makes sense to an accountant but to an accountancy illiterate Boss/Client it is very dangerous to say that my calculation is based on assumptions.

Comment: @paul - First, I'd argue that part of being a professional that helps people deal with their money is being able to help the financially illiterate understand "Yes, I can do this thing.  But it will cost you way more than you stand to save on the off chance there was an error.  I'll do it if you want, it's just not financially wise on your part."  But if they're willing to pay you to do the reconciliation and you presumably know how to put together an Excel spreadsheet to replicate the calculations, I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @JustinCave Let's go with the latter one. How do I put transactions line by line in an excel sheet? It will be very time consuming and error prone

Comment: Most banks and credit cards have the ability to download a file of transactions rather than going by printed statements.  There are software packages that do OCR but it would take a while to get such a process set up and running-- not sure the ROI would be there.

Comment: What are unfair calculations?  Math errors, non-existent purchases, 1ncorrect interest charges, late penalties for on-time payments?

Comment: @DJohnM you got it right.

Comment: @paul it's 2020, not 1980.  What kind of bank does your client use which has math errors, non-existent purchases, incorrect interest charges, late penalties for on-time payments?

Comment: @RonJohn First, there are banks that cleverly applies those charges and take the benefit of negligence. Secondly, consider this as a (hypothetical) problem, not get into whether it would exist or not. Sometimes we have to assume X, to solve problems without thinking whether it literally exists or not.

Comment: @paul I challenge you to to show me a US bank in 2020 which has math errors, non-existent purchases (due to bank issues, not stolen cards), incorrect interest charges and late penalties for on-time payments.  (Wells Fargo does not count because that's a different issue.)

Comment: @RonJohn I lost the challenge. Now, can you please help. If not bank, consider anything travel-agencies/medical-bills any.

Comment: Everyone is giving you sound, practical advice, and you're replying with hypotheticals. This makes me very suspicious.

Comment: LOLs ... A dodo bird running at speed 5km/hr how much time it will take to reach her nest 20kms away. Hey Hello, wrong question, Dodos are extinct. :)

Comment: What are you tasked with reconciling?  You have 60 credit card statements, ok.  What are you supposed to reconcile that against?  Do you also have the checking account statements that the credit card payments would have come from to determine that the correct amounts were withdrawn in time such that there’s no late fee?  Are you supposed to recreate the interest charges?  Or recreate foreign currency transaction fees? Otherwise you’re just typing a paper record in to Excel...

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have 5 years of records per client, but I don't think there is a need to go back that far.  If you find a mistake 5 years back, the credit card company won't care. The error was carried forward into the current and fixing it would be too hard. The terms and conditions probably only give you a few months to address an error.

If theses clients are a business then their accountant or tax advisor should already have these records. They would have had to use these records not just to double check the numbers but also to perform the required business and tax calculations. Getting the records from an accounting tool into a spreadsheet is another question for another site.

If these clients want you to use the paper records, then you should bill them for the amount of time it takes. Many credit cards will allow you to download the records going back x months. Some may allow you to go back even farther, but they may charge you for these additional months, but even $10 a month would be cheaper then paying somebody to enter the items by hand.

For future months you should either download the records directly from a website, or require the client to provide the downloaded data in something besides a hard copy or pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Since credit card interest is charged based on the amount of a transaction, the time elapsed since that transaction, and an interest rate that varies with time, there is no way to verify the interest calculations without entering all three components.

You can often get the date-stamped transaction list from the bank in a spreadsheet format. The interest rate may need to be be manually entered. Then all that remains is to code up a cumulative weighted sum column and adjust it for penalty interest, flat fees and the like, then check against the interest charged in each statement.